# Ignoring file in Git

Tags: git

We have a java repository which is handled through IntelliJ IDE. We have added a `.gitignore` file to the root of the repo, containing the following lines among other ones:

```
.iml
*/*iml
```

However, after cloning the repo and opening it with IntelliJ, it generates a new file `my.project.package.iml` which is not ignored by Git, it considers it as an untracked file.

I've also tried to ignore it through `git update-index --assume-unchanged my.project.package.iml`, but it doesn't take any effect. I've tried removing the file and regenerating it after applying this command, with no effect either.

Could someone explain my what's happening here?

**EDIT**

It seems that the issue with `.gitignore` file was that you should put `*.iml`instead of just `.iml`. But what happens with `git update-index --assume-unchanged` command? Why is it not taking any effect? I'm really curious about that...

Comment: What about `*.iml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `.gitignore` file as the following:

`*.iml
*/*iml`

e.g. add asterisk to the first row.